# Show an alert when lon/lat is near

Tags: ios

I have an application working on iOS devices getting constantly the current latitude and longitude from the device. I would like to show an alert when the user reaches a certain lon/lat.

Here is the long to be reached  : 2.39364456
Here is the lat to be reached : 48.84185814

When the user reaches this point, he should get an alert.

Unfortunately it doesn't work since the user doesn't always get to this exact point.

What I would like to do is : if you are NEAR to this point, in a certain range defined, then we pop up the alert.

I have no idea how to do this. I tried to implement long/lat to UTM converter and then try to work with UTM format but it was a failure.

Is it possible to work with the lon/lat's numbers which are after the comas to make a "range" to be in so the pop up shows ?

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: p.s. why are you trying to get to a [point off the coast of Somalia](https://www.google.com/maps/place/2%C2%B023'37.1%22N+48%C2%B050'30.7%22E/@2.3936446,48.8418581,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)?

Comment: Yes, assuming you meant a location in France, the _latitude_ should be +48.nnn and the _longitude_ should be +2.nnn.

Comment: Lol michael Dautermann, I suddenly inverted lon and lat. I now edited the post. So as you can see it is in France, Paris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
        CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

        if (currentLocation != nil) {
       CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        }
            CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];
            distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
      if(distance<yourDesiredDiustance)
      {
       show Alert
      }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for the *region monitoring* functionality that comes in Core Location in iOS.

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430836/ios-region-monitoring-in-background-mode) that talks about that.

And here is [some Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html).

And the latest [Apple documentation that talks about Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1).

When your app gets into the region you're watching, your app gets called with the CLLocationManager delegate ["`locationManager:didEnterRegion:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/cllocationmanagerdelegate_protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didEnterRegion:) method.  And that is where you can fire your UIAlert from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It really helped, I will perhaps use it later to optimize my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 locations, aCLLocationA which is position defined by you, and aCLLocationB user location which get's updated. Now what you do:

## Step 1

Find the distance by using this code between points on Map:

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [aCLLocationA distanceFromLocation:aCLLocationB];
```

## Step 2

```
if(distance<=yourRange)
{
    //You have to show popup, because your location is in range with that point
}
```